# How to get variable in Laravel blade @foreach loop from outer view

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

I have `blade` view with `@foreach` loop. In this `blade` view I also pass on `$user` variable in UserController. Inside `@foreach` I have code `{{ $user->getAvatar() }}`.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

@foreach($threads as $thread)
    <div class="media alert {{ $class }}">
        <img src="{{ $user->getAvatar() }}">
        <div class="media-body">
            <p>
            {{ $thread->latestMessage->body }}
            </p>
        </div>    
    </div>
@endforeach

@endsection
```

This is index() function in my controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $threads = Thread::getAllLatest()->get();
        return view('messenger.index', compact('threads', 'user'));
    }
```

I have error `Undefined variable: user`. `foreach` loop don't see variable from other part of view.

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: user (View:messenger\partials\thread.blade.php) (View: messenger\partials\thread.blade.php)
Previous exceptions
Undefined variable: user (View: messenger\partials\thread.blade.php) (0)
Undefined variable: user (0)
```

Comment: please add the full error message

Comment: You're calling the view `messenger.index` but the error is coming from `messenger\partials\thread.blade.php`. Are you showing us all the relevant view code? Are you calling a partial somewhere and not passing that variable to it?

Comment: Problem is simple. `@foreach` loop don't see variable from outside.

Comment: @SergeyS. share full relevant code, surely there is something that missing here

Answer (score 2):

In your case, please use this code on **return**

```
return View::make('messenger.index')

->with(compact('threads'))

->with(compact('user'));
```

You can use with **as many time as you want**. This will resolve your issue hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if variable has value or not, if laravel failed to get value of `$user->getAvatar()` it will definitely return error 
so just try following

```
@isset($user->getAvatar())

@endisset
```

Comment: variable have value. if i add `{{dd($user)}}` in blade template, i see object. But in `@foreach loop`, this variable is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
@foreach($threads as $thread)
    <div class="media alert {{ $class }}">
        <img src="{{ isset($user) ? $user->getAvatar : '' }}">
        <div class="media-body">
            <p>
            {{ $thread->latestMessage->body }}
            </p>
        </div>    
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining it above foreach loop

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<?php 
   $user_avatar = $user->getAvatar();
?>
@foreach($threads as $thread)
<div class="media alert {{ $class }}">
    <img src="{{ $user_avatar }}">
    <div class="media-body">
        <p>
        {{ $thread->latestMessage->body }}
        </p>
    </div>    
</div>
@endforeach

@endsection
```

Hope it Helps !

Comment: Undefined variable: user_avatar.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use `auth()` helper function instead

```
<img src="{{ auth()->user()->getAvatar() }}">
```

This way you don't need to pass it trough the controller.